# WinRT and missing Web API models for Amazon API access

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I was working with porting the sample from the link below to a Windows 8 Metro styled app

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480

Looks like many features from the web model are removed (or moved) in WinRT:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
HttpUtility.UrlDecode
HMAC / HMACSHA256
```

to name a few. Are there alternatives to these on WInRT? I looked online and there's very little insight.

Comment: Found Uri.EscapeDataString as an alternative for HttpUtility.UrlEncode - not much luck with the other keywords

Comment: Have you tried: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx#convert

Comment: Will see and update this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres source code for URLDecode here, and looks like **Uri.EscapeDataString** can be used for Encode.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid1A50096D8FA38302680B0EEDAC5B1CE1AEA855D0.aspx?s=%22Lawrence+Pit%22

copy the source code over, change the GetChars function to this

```
    static char [] GetChars (MemoryStream b, Encoding e)
    {
        return e.GetChars (b.ToArray(), 0, (int) b.Length);
    }
```

I had to use the code snippet from here to properly hash encrypt the string
http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Porting-to-WinRT/4df7586e1ef5400682eda00f0143b610

Answer (score 3):

Use methods from the [WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx) class instead:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string);
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(string);
```